# What is causing WebClient to return null from a rest call?

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, spring-webflux, spring-webclient

I have a basic Kotlin Spring app, and I want to make a rest call to return and print the json. I have the below code, but every time I make a call, it returns null. This happens to other rest calls as well. Do I need to make the call in a different way?

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val app = runApplication<NestpublisherApplication>(*args)

    val client = WebClient.create("https://api.kanye.rest")
    val type = object : ParameterizedTypeReference<String>() {}

    val result : Flux<String> = client.get()
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToFlux(type)
            .doOnNext{println("Iterating through")}
            .doOnError { println("ERROR: ${it.message}") }
}
```

Comment: Where do you see it returning null?

Comment: `result` is a `Flux<String>`. The flux would have the result. You can see that by printing `result.blockLast()`

Comment: That worked! If you post as an answer, I'll accept it. Thanks!!

Comment: blocking is bad and is a bad answer.

Comment: Since you use Kotlin you can also use coroutines. Wrap your code with `runBlocking` and call one of the `await...` methods.

Comment: @ThomasAndolf What would be a better approach?

Comment: @ThomasAndolf lets not blatantly say blocking is bad, coz there's nothing as bad or good in it. You can use `WebClient` for a blocking call or a non-blocking call. It all depends on the use-case.

Comment: @DanLargo I didn't mean to say that you need to use `result.blockLast()`. What I said is you are getting the response, just that you need to use it accordingly.

Comment: Better check out [this](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-5-webclient) and [this](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-webclient-resttemplate) to know more about using `WebClient`

Comment: What you need to decide is if you want to use `WebClient` to make a blocking call or a non-blocking call according to your use-case, and use it accordingly.

Comment: @MadhuBhat how about you instead of reading baeldungs often faulty blogpost and instead read the official webflux documentation. https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web-reactive.html#webflux-client-synchronous
`With Flux or Mono, you should never have to block in a Spring MVC or Spring WebFlux controller. Simply return the resulting reactive type from the controller method. The same principle apply to Kotlin Coroutines and Spring WebFlux, just use suspending function or return Flow in your controller method .`

Comment: or the official reactive documentation https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#_blocking_can_be_wasteful
`Usually, Java developers write programs by using blocking code. This practice is fine until there is a performance bottleneck. Then it is time to introduce additional threads, running similar blocking code. But this scaling in resource utilization can quickly introduce contention and concurrency problems.`

Comment: the WHOLE POINT with using webflux/reactive is to write non-blocking applications. If you introduce blocking code you are introducing bottlenecks, and can instead write regular imperative code instead. There are only a fixed set of working threads in a reactive application, it wont automatically scale these threads. So if you block one or many of them, the application wont spawn new ones, hence it will block and eventually go really really slow, because as new requests come in, the current threads are blocked with work.

Comment: @ThomasAndolf you should better calm down and understand what I'm trying to say. I know about the pros of non-blocking code and cons of blocking code. But if you're trying to say use non-blocking itself without fully understanding the context of the OP, what OP is trying to achieve, how the OP's app is architected, I believe that's incorrect. We can never say there are absolutely zero use-cases for using blocking code.

Comment: I definitely agree that we should prefer non-blocking over blocking code.

Comment: @MadhuBhat since you dont know the context of the application, you should not give advice in telling ppl that they should block. If it is a webflux application blocking is really bad, if its not, then blocking is fine. But, returning a mono/flux to the calling client works in both a webflux and springMVC application. So you should not give advice to ppl that potentially can be really really bad. Blocking is blatently bad, in webflux applications. So before answering you should ask for the context, which you did not.

Comment: @ThomasAndolf why is it so difficult for you to understand what I'm saying? When did I just say to use blocking code? The OP thought that they were not getting response using the client. `result is a Flux<String>. The flux would have the result. You can see that by printing result.blockLast()` What I just said was to show the OP that the client is indeed getting the response, just that it's in the flux and can be seen that way.

Comment: @ThomasAndolf and please control yourself over here, there's no need to be so rude and brash.

Comment: this is nothing personal, even though you seem to be taking it as such. Have a good day

Comment: @ThomasAndolf no harm done. Take care and have a good day.